# Opus Undefined reference while linking on Window

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, opus

After 4 hours of search, I cannot understand why there are some unresovled external symbal error while I link the library.

I'm using VS 2015.

```
    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _opus_encoder_create referenced in function "public: __thiscall Compressor::Compressor(int,int)" (??0Compressor@@QAE@HH@Z)   PortOpus    A:\sharedfolder\babel\client\Compressor.obj 1
```

I would like to know, why ? Plus I'm sure that the lib got these functions, as I've opened it with atom and ctrl+f the name.

Comment: @JonathanMee Well, actually, I need to make it works on window and *nix, so for the window part, I used MinGW to install g++. What would you suggest me instead of that ? And not VS please. :)

Comment: @Sorikairo: Nothing wrong with your choice of toolchain. So you checked the library for the missing symbols. *Where is the library located?* (In `A:\sharedfolder\babel\client\lib`, or elsewhere?) *What is the exact name of the library file?*

Comment: @JonathanMee: Neither helpful or funny.

Comment: @DevSolar I'm editing my question to give the information you need !

Comment: @DevSolar If the library can't be found that would give a different error. I'd suspect something like incompatible name mangling.

Comment: @Sorikairo Did you use `extern "C" {}` to wrap the included headers?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: The undefined references are unmangled, which is correct since Opus is a C library. But are you sure about the library naming? All the MinGW libraries on my MinGW setup are named `lib*.a`... (can't whip up a proof right now, busy elsewhere, and using the MinGW setup too seldom manually to be sure -- it's basically just a backend to the automated build system here on my box...)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It's already done by the header given with the library sources. So yes :)

Comment: @Sorikairo _"default name giving when building it with VS"_ So you build the library using Visual Studio? That won't work, you need to build it with MinGW g++. The compilers produce different formats (PE and ELF).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It makes god damn sense now !

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Now that I'm using VS, I still got the same error...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: The whole point of MinGW is to produce PE binaries that work for Windows (different name mangling schemes aside, but we've addressed that)...?!?